# How to set paginate params via query?

Tags: fastapi

One of my endpoints is supposed to be pageable. It's essentially just a wrapper around an external API, thus there's some workarounds unfortunately.

However, I'd like to know how I can set the `params: Params` via query parameters.

I expected there to be arguments `page` and `size` to be available as in `/search?page=2&size=10` declaring them.

Since I wasn't able to find a single example I thought I might ask.

```py
@search_router.get("/search")
def search(query: str, params: Params = Params(size=20), response_model=Page[dict]):

    result = ris_client.service.SearchDocuments({
           "DokumenteProSeite": PAGE_SIZE[params.size],
           "Seitennummer": params.page
    })

    results = result["results"]
    hits = results["hits"]
    content = results["references"]

    return paginate(
        content,
        params,
        length_function=lambda _: int(hits["value"])
    )
```

I know I could expose these parameters myself like so:

```py
@search_router.get("/search")
def search(query: str, size: int = 20, page: int = 0, response_model=Page[dict]):
   params = Params(size=size, page=page)
   # ...
   return paginate(
        content,
        params,
        length_function=lambda _: int(hits["value"])
    )
```

but why is it then that I see the `Params` class in the function signature in almost every tutorial?

Comment: I'm guessing when you see `params: Params`, it's assigned with `= Depends()`? i.e. as shown in the fastapi-pagination tutorial (since you didn't specify where the `Params` class comes from). `response_model` is also a parameter to the view decorator (`.get`), not to the view function itself.

Answer (score 2):

This [`Params`](https://github.com/uriyyo/fastapi-pagination/blob/main/fastapi_pagination/default.py#L13) from fastapi-pagination is just a small helper class, that does some prevalidation for you:

```py
class Params(BaseModel, AbstractParams):
    page: int = Query(1, ge=1, description="Page number")
    size: int = Query(50, ge=1, le=100, description="Page size")

    def to_raw_params(self) -> RawParams:
        return RawParams(
            limit=self.size,
            offset=self.size * (self.page - 1),
        )
```

You can use it instead of explicitly passing those parameters to your endpoint.